# How to prevent crashing of session in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

I have provided with the training loop below, but while executing it the session is getting crashed i need some way to prevent it.

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
for batch_images in dataset:
# Generate noise for the generator
noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, latent_dim])

```
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:

        generated_frames = generator(noise, training=True)

        # Get discriminator predictions for real and fake frames
        real_output = discriminator(batch_images, training=True)
        fake_output = discriminator(generated_frames, training=True)

        # Calculate the generator and discriminator losses
        gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
        disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    # Compute the gradients of the generator and discriminator with respect to their loss
    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    # Apply the gradients to update the generator and discriminator variables
    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))

    # Train the generator to predict the future frames
    for i in range(num_frames):
        with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape:
            # Generate noise for each frame
            noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, latent_dim])

            # Generate a single frame
            generated_frame = generator(noise, training=True)

            # Calculate the generator loss for predicting the next frame
            next_frame_loss = next_frame_loss_function(batch_images[:, i+1], generated_frame)

        gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(next_frame_loss, generator.trainable_variables)

        generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
```

I have tried changing runtime in TPU as well as adding tf.keras.backend.clear_session() after each epoch but it doesn't worked.

Comment: How soon does it crash after it begins running? Does it crash only after you change the runtime type? If you're using GPU or TPU and the code doesn't actually necessitate it then colab will "crash" and disconnect the session (because Google's angry you're using resources that your code doesn't need). Or maybe you're exceeding the RAM which causes it to crash.

Comment: The code crashed after approximately 1 minute and 54 seconds during my most recent attempt to run it.

Comment: If you've tried running it on `None`, `GPU`, and `TPU` and it still crashes after a short amount of time then it's most likely a RAM issue.